# External cPanel Login and redirect

Tags: php, cpanel

i'm trying to automatically login into cPanel and then redirect the user to the Awstats page.
But i'm running into some troubles.
The only working method i found is this:

```
<form method="post" id="login-form" action="http://domain.com:2082/login">
    <input type="hidden" name="login_theme" id="login_theme" value="cpanel">
    <input type="hidden" name="goto_uri" id="goto_uri" value="awstats.pl?config=euqueroinvestir.com&lang=pt">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="myuser">
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" value="mypass">
</form>
<script>window.onload = function() { document.forms["login-form"].submit(); }</script>
```

But, as you can see, if the user see the source-code, the password will be explicit in plain text. I can't do that. So i tried with cUrl, but now i'm having problems with headers, cookies and such.

This is my last attempt:

```
 $url = "http://domain.com:2082/login";

 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=myuser&pass=mypass");
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
 $body = substr($result, $header_size);
 curl_close($curl);

 $header = str_replace("\r", '', $header);
 $header = explode("\n", $header);

 foreach ($header as $h) {
     header ($h);
 }
 $parts = explode( 'URL=', $result);
 $session_parts = explode( '/frontend/', $parts[1]);
 $token = $session_parts[0];

 header('Location: http://domain.com:2082'.$token.'/awstats.pl?config=domain.com&ssl=&lang=pt');
```

With this i can get a security token, and the foreach($header as $h) loop is me trying to set the header and cookies from the cUrl client to the user browser.

Every help will be appreciated.
And yes, i searched through the google a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but thought I would throw out an answer since no one else has responded.  Maybe it will help someone else trying this too.

The reason you're not able to get this working is because cPanel validates the IP address of the user.  Your cURL script is housed on your server with its IP, and the user trying to login has their own IP address.

Check out the cPanel (x3) login form, there's not even a form field to submit your IP address, so it's being retrieved solely on the server side to prevent spoofing.

```
<form id="login_form" action="/login/" method="post" target="_top">
    <div class="input-req-login"><label for="user">Username</label></div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon username-container">
        <input name="user" id="user" autofocus="autofocus" value="" placeholder="Enter your username." class="std_textbox" type="text"  tabindex="1" required>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px;" class="input-req-login"><label for="pass">Password</label></div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon password-container">
        <input name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter your account password." class="std_textbox" type="password" tabindex="2"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="login-btn">
            <button name="login" type="submit" id="login_submit" tabindex="3">Log in</button>
        </div>

                                    </div>
    <div class="clear" id="push"></div>
</form>
```